# Accessibility automatically reading the first element

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have an iOS application and I'm adding accessibility to it.

When a screen gets pushed the voice over automatically reads the first element on the screen - in my case, it reads my back button -
 a `UINavigationBarButton` on my `UINavigationBar`.

If I disable the accessibility from the back button - it will read my screen title instead + it will not read the back button when the user touches the back button.

So... How can I tell the voice over to shut up when I push a new screen? only talk when I tell it to or when the user is touching an element.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VoiceOver will automatically read the first element of content when "Screen Changed" type of events occur. It does so by pushing a UIAccessibilityScreenChanged notification. The system will do this for you on certain types of transitions, segues, etc. You can't keep this from happening, nor should you. This is desired behavior.  If you want to send focus to a more helpful location, something other than your UINavigationBar, you could consider posting the `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` yourself, and supplying it with a different view to focus.

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, viewToFocus);
```

Comment: UIAccessibilityPostNotification does not work at all it still jumps to the 1st element

Comment: Check your timing. Make sure that content is rendered before you post the notification and that the ViewController's own internal focus event doesn't trigger after yours! This usually involves a delay of some kind, since the appropriate callback to override does not exist, or overriding it removes essential behaviors.